# How can I reload a github repository in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

In first of my code in google Colab I clone a github repository:

```
 !git clone https://github.com/xyz/abc.git
```

Sometimes I need to modify the github repository and then run the code again. However, if I don't do `Factory reset runtime`, the changes won't be reflected after clone! It seems they are cached somewhere. I want to know if there are easier solutions instead of resetting runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are changing the github items somewhere else and simply want to take the latest into your Colab notebook. One option is to use `git pull` but you have to do that from the folder where your repository was downloaded. For your example, you would do this in one cell (note no !).

```
cd abc
```

Then in another cell, do this

```
!git pull
```

You would need to change directory back to where you started so do this.

```
cd ..
```

Another alternative is to delete the complete folder and do the clone again.

```
!rm -r abc
!git clone https://github.com/xyz/abc.git
```

Comment: Thanks `pulling` works, however I am not sure about removing;  because I remember I tried that too.